# SUMIF Formula - Ranges

Tags: excel

When inputting the "range" and "sum_range" for the SUMIF formula, is there a way to do so if the "range" is situated horizontally while the "sum_range" is situated vertically?

The formula only works for me if I transpose the "sum_range" from vertical to horizontal, and I really do not want to do that as these ranges are part of a larger table, so it would look awkward if I did. I also do not want to make an 'invisible' transposed copy of the range either.

Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With vertical sum range in `A2:A10` and criteria range in `B1:J1` you could use `MMULT` function like this

`=MMULT((B1:J1="d")+0,A2:A10)`

the "row" always has to be the first argument here

Comment: There are three components to the SUMIF function: range, criteria, and sum_range. My "range" is B2:E2, my "criteria" is "2", and my "sum_range" is W8:W11. How does the Transpose formula work here? I tried putting into the box but a 0 came up, the value should be a 2.

Comment: Try this formula `=MMULT((B2:E2=2)+0,W8:W11)` - you probably don't need quotes around the `2`

Comment: It worked, I didn't know if what I wanted to do was possible. Thank you very much, I appreciate it :P

Comment: Does this formula work if the first range is on another excel workbook?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem as long as you correctly reference that range, e.g. if you want B2:E2 on sheet2 try this: `=MMULT((Sheet2!B2:E2=2)+0,W8:W11)` - note W8:W11 has to be fully populated - if not try `=MMULT((Sheet2!B2:E2=2)+0,W8:W11+0)`

Comment: Okay thanks, and one last question. Is there anyway to differentiate between a blank cell, which would be "", and a cell with a 0 in it? When I try putting a 0 into the formula, it counts all cells that are blank as well.

Comment: Good answer to what was a poor question

Comment: In that case you can add another condition to check that the cell isn't blank, i.e. `=MMULT((B2:E2=0)*(B2:E2<>""),W8:W11+0)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Transpose` function in an array formula like this:

```
=SUM((A1:A8="d")*TRANSPOSE(A9:H9))
```

You have to enter it as an array formula, i.e. do not press <kbd>Enter</kbd> but <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.  (The formula gets put in curly brackets.)
In this sample, the array `A1:A8` is compared row-wise to `d`, which is computed to 1 or 0, and then multiplied with the corresponding row in the second array, and the results are summed up.

Comment: The OP pointed out in the question they didn't want to `TRANPOSE`

Comment: @brettdj My reading of the OP is that he doesn't want to modify the sheet by transposing the data. Using `TRANSPOSE` in the formula is one way to achieve that.

Comment: @brettdj I think you're confusing things. He didn't want to have a transposed copy of the cells on the sheet. The `Transpose` here is just a calculation inside the function.

Comment: You can use this some approach replacing SUM by SUMPRODUCT and avoiding the Ctrl Shift Enter. And, for me, a much more clean solution than MMULT (+1)

Comment: @CRonado I tried that - I don't really understand why but `SUMPRODUCT` doesn't seem to get the right result that way (tested in Excel 2007).

Comment: There are three components to the SUMIF function: range, criteria, and sum_range.

My "range" is B2:E2, my "criteria" is "2", and my "sum_range" is W8:W11. How does the Transpose formula work here? I tried putting into the box but a 0 came up, the value should be a 2.

Comment: Re SUMPRODUCT - when you use with TRANSPOSE "array entry" is always required

Comment: If you mean pressing ctrl+shift+enter, then I did.

Comment: You'd also have to use 2 without quotes as per my MMULT suggestion, i.e. `=SUM((B2:E2=2)*TRANSPOSE(W8:W11))`